# .net standard console implement healthcheck

Tags: .net-standard

Is it possible to use similar healthcheck for .net standard classic like .net core web app?

Something like

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                xx
            });
```

I wan to know if console app is running and web socket client is working correctly